# React-Native — Passing data between a Component and a Class

Tags: javascript, variables, react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to get my head around passing data between files, specifically between a React-Native Component and a Class. The objective is to pass data from a Component to a Class that handles API calls. Thank you in advance.

My questions are:

- How can I pass data from Component to Class and Class to Component?
- Does AsyncStorage work in this situation?

**Pseudo-code**

First

- Pass data from this.state in Component to Class
- Receive data in Class and do something
- Pass data from this.data in Class to Component
- Receive data in Component and do something

Second

- Retrieve data in Component from a function in Class
- Retrieve data in Class from a Component

**Component.js**

This file will be actively generating data to Class.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';

// Custom ***********************************************************************
let Class = require('./Class')

export class Component extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            parent: "Parent data", // Access to this in the Class.js
            child: null,
        }
    };

    _componentData = () => {
        let componentData = "Func component data." // Access to this in the Class.js
        return componentData
    }



    render() {
        return(
            <View>
            </ View>
        );
    }
};
```

**Class.js**

This file will receive data from Component.js and handle API calls.

```
import Component from './Component'

class Class {
    constructor() {
        this.data = {
            component: null,
            class: "Class data" // Access to this in the Component.js
        }
    }

    static _classData = () => {

        let classData = "Func class data" // Access to this in the Component.js
        return classData
    }

};

module.exports = Class;
```

Answer (score 0):

you code is complicated but as i understand you want to get data from another page 
i once done his in one project 

**main file**

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {                   
        superBasket: []
    };


}
static basketUpdater(newItems) {
    let basket = context.state.superBasket;

    this.setState({superBasket: newItems});


}
```

and i send main.basketUpdater as prop to second file

```
 this.props.basketUpdater(basket);
```

this can also cause mutation base on example if run in to one i will be glad to solve it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I cannot access props to a Class. I tried without success. Passing data between React components I understand how to do it. I am trying to pass data from a `Component` to a `Class`.

Comment: hello diego-oriani i suddenly get an idea that one thing is you can do is make component that have null render return ,this way you can have your data generation there and don't affect other code's

Comment: Hi Nima. Yes, that is an option but unfortunately not what I am want to learn. I am trying to understand how I can pass data from a `Component` to a `Class` (vice-versa). The whole Component to Component is not an issue as React-Native handles it very well. Thank you for the reply anyway.